# Aggregating data from Discourse

Tags: sql, postgresql, discourse

I currently have a SQL query that returns the number of topics created in a category each week.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS topic_count, 
    DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) AS week 
FROM topics
WHERE 
    topics.deleted_at IS NULL AND 
    topics.category_id = (
        SELECT id 
        FROM categories 
        WHERE categories.name LIKE 'Category Name'
    ) 
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)
ORDER BY week DESC
```

How can I alter this query so that I can see the topic_count for each category in the categories table? The resulting columns I would like to see are:

- Category 1 Name topic count
- Category 2 Name topic count
- ...
- Category n Name topic count
- Week

Answer (score 1):

Add the category name to the query and group by it in addition to the week:

```
SELECT 
    categories.name,
    DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at) AS week 
    COUNT(*) AS topic_count, 
FROM topics,
     categories
WHERE 
    topics.deleted_at IS NULL AND 
AND topics.category_id = categories.id
AND categories.name LIKE 'Category Name'
GROUP BY categories.name, DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)
ORDER BY categories.name, week DESC
```

Comment: After correcting some syntax errors and scoping `created_at` to the topics column, this gives me the data I'm looking for, but not the format I'm looking for.

Comment: I thought I was fairly clear in the resulting data columns I would like to see in my original question.

Comment: Ok, I will leave it to the rest of horde of people who are attempting to answer your question to do a better job at it and interpret you question properly! :)

Comment: I didn't mean to sound ungrateful. Thank you for your help. You have helped me get one step closer to the solution.